# Performance difference between these methods

Tags: php, html, echo

Is there any advantages/disadvantages to either of these statements over the other one:

```
<?php 
$test = 1;
$test2 = 2;
$test3 = $test + $test2;
echo "<p>Hello World</p>"; 
?>
```

OR

```
<?php 
$test = 1;
$test2 = 2;
$test3 = $test + $test2;
?>
<p>Hello World</p>
```

What i'm asking is, if i'm outputting a page using PHP should i keep closing the php tags and stick normal HTML in or echo out the HTML? Which is better?

Comment: The difference is certainly negligible.

Comment: repeated question like this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/505642/escape-html-to-php-or-use-echo-which-is-better

Comment: What do you think is easier to maintain? The first or the second? Imagine with more HTML.

Comment: The first is easier to maintain, if you have not so much html, because the open and closing tags can get very confusing, if you have many of them all over your code. The second one is easier, if you have much html, because see Yeroons answer ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you want do be realy exact, there are three options:

the slowest:

```
echo "<p>Hello World</p>";
```

a bit faster (no need to check for inline-valiables because of single quotes):

```
echo '<p>Hello World</p>';
```

the fastest (no php-interpreting at all):

```
<p>Hello World</p>
```

but between all of this, the difference would be so minimalistic that you won't ever notice it - much more important: make your code redable and do it the same way everywhere, so nobody who's reading your code (and has to maintain it) gets confused. i personally would prefer the third method (so i can use code-completition in my IDE), but it's your choice - i know a lot of people who output everything using echo.

**EDIT:** to be complete, there are some more possibilitys i didn't mentioned like [heredoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc)- and [nowdoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc)-syntax, but this are basically the same as double/single-quotes... also, you could write [print](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.print.php) instead of echo and so on, but that wouldn't make a difference.

Answer (score 3):

Method 2 is cleaner IMHO because you separate PHP code from HTML. Your IDE (if you use any) can parse your HTML tags and autocomplete them, and spot any typo's.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a PHP programmer but I would assume the 2nd method is faster, because PHP doesn't have to process the echo language construct, allocate buffer and all that stuff. It is also cleaner, and less of a hassle to modify the HTML.

Also, it would be wise to learn to use a template engine for your HTML in order to separate concerns. Smarty was popular a couple years ago, I don't know if it's still is.

Answer (score 0):

Although the difference is negligible, you should stick normal outputing out of PHP tags. Echo command will have to be parsed by PHP interpreter and then sent as output.

Answer (score 0):

The only difference is that with `echo();` you instruct PHP to process the code, otherwise, there is no difference at all.

One way or another, the result is exactly the same and for performance, there is almost no differences at all. Like... How much time PHP needs to process that `echo();`? *I think with miliseconds you could run in problems calculating numbers that small. Hehe.*