# Output Html with PHP Template

Tags: php, performance, templates

I am building my own template system. 
I am asking myself what is the best/fastest way to Output templated html. Example: body.php

Method1: Building a echostring

```
$layout = '
<body>
<div id="header">

        '.$header.'
</div>
</body>';
```

Method2: Html with encapsulated `php` areas

```
<body>
<div id="header">

      <?php  echo $header; ?>

</div>
</body>
```

What is your recommendation and why?

Comment: [Horses for courses](http://www.usingenglish.com/reference/idioms/horses+for+courses.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lot of people will opt for separation of languages, but as others stated, this is more opinion based. [This question was asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5156377/is-it-allways-better-to-output-html-code-in-a-php-file-with-echo) also if you're looking for more views on the situation.

Answer (score 1):

This is more like opinion based. Both ways work but I personally find the 2nd way to be easier to spot errors.

Answer (score 1):

I would say Method 2 because its a bit easier to manage and see your code this way.

One of the biggest problems i have dealt with is trying to decipher html when its in a string, typically your editor will not color code html within a string so it becomes hard to see and make changes to HTML.

If your lazy and dont want your own templating system, Codeigniter is pretty awesome and has a lot of resources to help.

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: i will have a look thx!