# Is it more efficent to write dom elements with php or html?

Tags: php, html, performance, pagespeed

I am building a site that is a mix of php and html, my static content is in html, dynamic/database driven content is obviously echo'd out with php. I have however found myself at times adding html tags with php, that does not need to be in php, I was just wondering is there a difference in efficiently between writing... for example...

```
<?php
$result = mysql_query("SOME QUERY") or die(mysql_error());
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
echo "<ul id=\"someid\">";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
echo "<li>RAR RAR</li>";
}
echo "</ul>";
echo "<div class=\"clearfix\"></div>";
?>
```

or

```
<ul id="someid">
<?php
$result = mysql_query("SOME QUERY") or die(mysql_error());
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
echo "<li>RAR RAR</li>";
}
?>
</ul>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
```

Any difference in speed? Non at all? I am just interested. Cheers

Comment: Don't wonder about it. If you want to waste some time, you can test it (the only way to make sure what is quicker in your case most of the time), but in the end: this is a micro-optimisation, will be completely lost between network latency, I/O and other time consuming things and is not worth putting effort in optimizing.

Comment: Don't worry about which one is faster (and if you mean "faster", say "faster").  Worry about which one is easier for you as a human to read, as well as whoever else has to maintain the code.

Answer (score 2):

The best practice in general is not to mix HTML with PHP like you did in BOTH of your examples. You want to open the document with <kbd><?php</kbd> and never close it. Echo HTML code instead, possibly using [heredoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) syntax.

Performance-wise there isn't any difference that would matter. It's like wondering if <kbd>is_null</kbd> is quicker then <kbd>===null</kbd> - yes, the <kbd>===</kbd> is marginally faster, but noone cares, because single foreach loop can have many times greater impact on performance then this.

So don't worry! Write it in the way you find **cleaner** to read, as this makes a difference. Whatever echo is faster then raw output or not - it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

First off - you should stop using MySQL. It is deprecated since PHP 5.5 and no longer maintained. You have 2 alternatives: MySQLi and PDO. Also, you should remove `or die()`, as you don't want your customers(or even worse - potential hackers) seeing error messages :)

It is faster to not echo html content, simply because if you do, php will have to parse more content. The difference is very small though, probably not even notable.

There is another question discussing this: [Escape HTML to PHP or Use Echo? Which is better?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/505642/escape-html-to-php-or-use-echo-which-is-better)

Comment: I would also add that pure HTML is more maintainable in the sense that it's a lot easier to read the code. (It's easier to keep things organized when you avoid mixing things.

Comment: Yes, you're right. These are pretty much covered in the topic I just linked, so I don't think there's a need to into a lot of detail