# PHP code optimization technique during echo statement

Tags: php

I am coding a php site from scratch.
I am confused whether the following two codes are exactly same or are different with respect to server load and execution speed.

Code 1:

```
<ul>
<?php
    $i =0; 
    while($i < 10){
        echo '<li>'.$row['database_data'].'</li>';
        $i++;
    }
?>
</ul>
```

Code 2:

```
<ul>
<?php
$i =0; 
while($i < 10)
{ ?>
<li><?php echo $row['database_data'];?></li>
<?php
$i++;
}
?>
</ul>
```

Comment: I wouldn't know about performance differences between the two approaches without testing, but the second approach would make the code harder to read and maintain down the road.

Comment: The performance difference is in this case negligible if any.

Comment: Also, this looks a lot like premature optimization

Comment: @GennadiyLitvinyuk it's just an example. Actually I have much code in <li>  element. Will it make a difference in loading speed.

Comment: @AlexAndrei Readability is not a matter of concern to me. I want to know that which approach one should follows ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Escape HTML to PHP or Use Echo? Which is better?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/505642/escape-html-to-php-or-use-echo-which-is-better)

Comment: They're not different regarding to "speed". The "speed" doesn't depend on the execution of PHP but about how much data you're transferring and how fast the browser can render it. Also, both snippets are equally ugly to read, maintain and write.

Comment: This question could be answered trivially by clocking actual execution time. Expect the difference to be hardly measurable.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** The thread linked to by @pemap modder seems to have the correct answer within it, the manual states:

> For outputting large blocks of text, dropping out of PHP parsing mode is generally more efficient than sending all of the text through echo or print.
>
> http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php

<strike>The first one from my **quick** tests was faster.</strike>

- First Version Output: **Time taken: 0.14 seconds**
- Second Version Output: **Time taken: 0.17 seconds**

I would assume the reason for that is because you do not jump in/out of PHP constantly, which based of what I was taught, is the best way to go about this. If memory serves constantly jumping from PHP to HTML and back slows down the interpreter, although I can't completely confirm that without researching it more.